# What is the correct syntax for multiple images and captions in HTML?

Tags: html

In HTML, if I have multiple images and want to caption each one, which is the correct syntax?

A

```
<figure>
    <img src="images/img1.jpg">
    <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="images/img2.jpg">
    <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
</figure>
```

or B

```
<figure>
    <img src="images/img1.jpg">
    <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
    <img src="images/img2.jpg">
    <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Have you not tried both to see which works?

Comment: Yes, both work. B provides an additional space between images, but I was wondering if one was syntactically correct.

Comment: Might be useful --> [The Right Way to Use Figure & Figcaption Elements](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-the-right-way-to-use-figure-and-figcaption-elements/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like based off the spec, it would be your first one.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element

> 4.4.11 The figure element
>
> Content model:
>
> Either: One figcaption element followed by flow content.
>
> Or: Flow content followed by one figcaption element.
>
> Or: Flow content.

So basically each figure element should only contain a single figcaption.

Answer (score 2):

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) for the `figure` element content model says:

> Either: One figcaption element followed by flow content.
>   Or: Flow content followed by one figcaption element.

I think that's pretty clear that a `figure` should represent one thing. So option A is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the figure tag, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure):

> The HTML  element represents self-contained content,
>   frequently with a caption (), and is typically referenced
>   as a single unit.